# Javascript: Get Length of a String without Length Propery, And with Slice

Tags: javascript

I know, it's a weird one! But why does this not work?

```
function getStringLength(string) {

  // see how many substrings > 0 can be built
  // log that number & return

  var subString = string.slice();
  var counter = 0;

  while (subString !== '') {
    counter++;
    subString = subString.slice(counter);
  }

  return counter;
}

var output = getStringLength('hello');

console.log(output); // --> expecting 5, but getting 3 (??)
```

I really want to do it with slice! The original challenge was to not use the length property, and I figured this out, which works fine:

```
function getStringLength(string) {

  var long = 0;

  while (string[long] !== undefined) {
    long++;
  }

  return long;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you were mutating your string, this should work for you

```js
function getStringLength(string) {

  // see how many substrings > 0 can be built
  // log that number & return

  var subString = string.slice();
  var counter = 0;

  while (subString !== '') {
    counter++;
    subString = subString.slice(1);
  }

  return counter;
}

var output = getStringLength('hello');

console.log(output); // 5
```

The main difference was that I was doing

```
subString = subString.slice(1);
```

instead of

```
subString = subString.slice(counter);
```

which always decreased length by 1

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the code `substring.slice(counter)` First time, you chop off 1 character. Then you chop off 2 characters *from the already-chopped substring*. Either chop off 1 at a time, or chop off the increasing amount from the original string. So that's either `substring.slice(1)` or `string.slice(counter)`

```js
function getStringLength(string) {

  // see how many substrings > 0 can be built
  // log that number & return

  var subString = string.slice();
  var counter = 0;

  while (subString !== '') {
    counter++;
    subString = substring.slice(1);
  }

  return counter;
}

var output = getStringLength('hello');

console.log(output);
```

Comment: If someone posts an answer exactly like yours, before you, you should consider deleting your answer

Comment: There were no answers when i constructed mine, but thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I was also writing an answer, deleted because a similar answer was posted

Comment: thank you Nicholas, your text description was spot-on and I see where I went wrong

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
function getStringLength(arr){
  return arr.lastIndexOf(arr.slice(-1))+1
}

var output = getStringLength('hello');
console.log(output);
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gGPWEE?editors=1111

**Option2:** As type of array is object,below option works too

```
function getStringLength(arr){
  return Object.keys(arr).pop()*1 + 1
}

var output = getStringLength('hello');
console.log(output);
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PJZmgg?editors=1111

Check the below updated options to handle empty and numbers 
https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GMoQgy?editors=1111
https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YrweWr?editors=1111

Comment: The first option fails if the string ends with a character that can be found earlier on in the string.

Comment: Thanks @MarcodeZeeuw, I have updated it to lastIndexOf , it should work fine now :)

Comment: Very close, both options don't like empty strings though hehe

Comment: oh ...thanks @MarcodeZeeuw :) ... Check these out and updated to check only strings and handled empty and string parameters :)   https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GMoQgy?editors=1111 and  https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YrweWr?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a slightly shorter answer:

```js
function getStringLength(string) {
  var counter = 0;
  while (string.slice(counter)) {
    counter++;
  }

  return counter;
}

var outputHello = getStringLength('hello');
console.log(outputHello); // 5

var outputEmpty = getStringLength('');
console.log(outputEmpty); // 0
```